# Django inlineformset unique validation error when one is deleted

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model that has a `unique_together` value.  In an inlineformset if I have two forms with the same unique values together I get a validation error on the second one as a `non_field_errors`.  The second one is a "new" one in that it doesn't have an `id` value.  If the second one is marked as deleted then it works fine, but if the first one is marked for deletion (the one with the `id` value and already existing in the database) then I still get the validation error on the second form.

I'm expecting it to delete the first form object and then create a new object with the same `unique_together` values.  There's a lot of moving parts with models and forms and I'm not really sure what's going wrong so I'm not sure how to work around this.  I've gotten the same result in Django 1.10 and Django 1.11.